# Error when i am trying to create a repository in my cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Sorry for my english ,  i am trying to create a Repository in my cluster, I get an error"the repository name already existed but it's not true, it does not appear in the repository list , i can't delete it and i can't create it too, anyone knows how can i solve this problem or the cause of this bug  ?

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ddk.png)

[list of repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaXBB.png)

I have tried to delete the repository via the oracle cloud shell but it shows that the repository does not exist

Answer (score 0):

A repository of the same name probably exists in an other compartment within your tenancy.

In Oracle's model you can't have two repositories with the same name, even if they are in separate compartments.

Comment: I  have only one compartment with repository

Comment: Can you please post a more complete error message? The image you posted above is truncated.